# Extract string from variable passed in parameter

Tags: perl, telnet

My Perl script needs ARG 0 and ARG 1 which are gived by web application ./telnet 10.10.10.10 78-0/1/1

i want to take from ARG1 only 0/1/1 and not 78-0/1/1 
and these value are different each time here on other exemple :

./telnet 10.10.10.10 90-0/2/2   so i need only 0/2/2 
Some one help please !!!!!

Answer (score 4):

You can use substitution to remove everything up to a dash:

```
my $string = '90-0/2/2';
$string = s/^.+-//;
```

If you want to be more specific, you can remove only digits:

```
$string =~ s/^[0-9]+-//;
```

- `^` matches the beginning of the string.
- `.` matches anything (except for newline).
- `+` means the previous thing should be repeated at least once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Perl's split subroutine.

```
my $ARG1 = '90-0/2/2';
my $required_part = (split(/-/,$ARG1))[1];
```

Now, $required_part contains **0/2/2**

Comment: Thank you Pradeep this is exactly what i looked for

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the part you don't want, you can capture the part that you *do* want

```
my ($param) = $ARGV[1] =~ /-(.+)/
```